# How to allow searching for users but not allow listing users in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am trying to implement a function in my application to let an authenticated user search for another user by entering the user's email address.   I am trying to figure out the best way to implement the security rules in firebase to allow this type of searching, but to NOT allow a logged in user to simply list all users via /users.

Currently I have this security rule:

```
  "users" : {
    ".indexOn" : "email",
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
    }
```

This clearly lets any authenticated user read the entire users collection.  Removing this line:

```
".read": "auth != null"
```

fixes this, but now I can no longer search for a user via email.  What is the recommended approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has two rights you can grant:

- read
- write

There is no separate right to allow searching, so that means that anyone who can search a node can also read that node.

But there probably is a workaround to solve your problem. If we assume that you have a users node like this:

```
users
   twitter:4368352
       id:4368352
       name: "lestyn Lewis"
       email: "lewis@lestyn.net"
   twitter:209103
       id:209103
       name: "Frank van Puffelen"
       email: "puf@stackoverflow.com"
```

*Hint: it would be nice if you could update your question and include the actual structure of your users node.*

With the above structure, you'd have to give the users `.read` rights to all nodes under `Users`. This would allow them to read not only the email addresses and ids, but also any other information you might keep on them.

To give your users access to only a subset of this data, you can duplicate that data into another node. So if you want to allow all users to search on email address, then you need to add a node that maps email addresses to uids:

```
users
   twitter:4368352
       id:4368352
       name: "lestyn Lewis"
       email: "lewis@lestyn.net"
   twitter:209103
       id:209103
       name: "Frank van Puffelen"
       email: "puf@stackoverflow.com"
email_to_uid:
    "lewis@lestyn.net": "twitter:4368352"
    "puf@stackoverflow.com": "twitter:209103"
```

You can then give all users rights to search, but only give access to the full user settings to a more limited set of users:

```
"users" : {
  ".indexOn" : "email",
  "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth === $uid",
      ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
  }
},
"email_to_uid" {
    ".read": "auth != null"
}
```

Note that you are essentially building your own index here, similar to what `".indexOn": "email"` does, so that you can control what information goes in it and who can access it.

Comment: Thank you, I would have accepted this earlier but didn't get an email or it got eaten by the spam folder.  This is the approach I was thinking of, still don't like that it allows a logged in user to list all of my users' email addresses if they know what they are doing, but it is an improvement.  Thank you.

Comment: Given that "being able to search" requires that you are able to read that information, there is not much you can do about this except: setting up an intermediate server/service that does the searches.

Comment: So if the user's email address changes, I take it that some logic needs to be implemented to update the key in the index with the new email address?